# Load Specific Tab Component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a several tabs in my react app and i only wanted to load that specific tab when i click it.
Right now, my problem is that other tabs is also rendering when i click a specific tab. I have use `console.log` to see if other tabs is rendering and is really is. How can i prevent that from happening. I wanted to load a tab only when i click it.

Pls see my codesandbox here:
[CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/tabs-material-ui-react-z3gt9)

```
  <div>
      <AppBar position="static" color="inherit" className={classes.root}>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          indicatorColor="primary"
          textColor="primary"
          variant="scrollable"
          scrollButtons="auto"
          aria-label="scrollable auto tabs example"
        >
          <Tab label="Users" component={Link} to="/users" {...a11yProps(0)} />
          <Tab
            label="Products"
            component={Link}
            to="/products"
            {...a11yProps(1)}
          />
          <Tab label="Sales" component={Link} to="/sales" {...a11yProps(2)} />
        </Tabs>
      </AppBar>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={0}>
        <Users />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={1}>
        <Products />
      </TabPanel>
      <TabPanel value={value} index={2}>
        <Sales />
      </TabPanel>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should separate the task of getting tab value from pathname into a separated utility function. Because when you switch between tab, value is set, trigger `handleChange` and then cause the pathname to be changed, which also result in function in `useEffect` (you use to get tab value from pathname) is also triggered too, result in unexpected behavior

```js
const getTabFromPathname = (pathname) => {
  switch (pathname) {
    case "/users":
      return 0;
    case "/products":
      return 1;
    case "/sales":
      return 2;
    default:
      return 0;
  }
};

function TabComponent(props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(
    getTabFromPathname(props.history.location.pathname)
  );

  const handleChange = (event, newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  // ...
}
```

Below is forked codesandbox for fixes

[image: Edit Tabs-Material-UI-React (forked)]

Comment: Nice! Thanks hgb123